# Control VLC from Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, vlc

I'm running [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) (a media player) in Windows 7. Is there way to control (as in: play, pause, set volume) a running instance of VLC from Python?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can control it [via telnet](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch05.html) (with [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html)). There are also [libvlc bindings](http://wiki.videolan.org/Libvlc), but I'm not sure you can use that to control an existing VLC instance.

Comment: Thanks .. though I wonder if there is a COM interface for VLC. That way, I can control VLC without having to configure it (by passing `--intf` program argument, for instance).

Comment: You can use the python bindings to control your own instance, if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

As a general alternative to already mentioned solutions it's good to know about [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.openqa.org/)

**UPDATE:**

Check out [swapy](http://code.google.com/p/swapy/) for a way to with pywinauto more easily.

Comment: @Tony Ruza PyWinAuto has no documentation or wiki page. How do I know if it supports vlc? Or what exactly is in its API?

Comment: @Radu It approaches GUI automation in a general way, no application specific support is needed or built in. There is documentation but I agree that it's lacking (links in the bottom of the page from the post).